# How do I change the location of the html-template folder in a flex app?

Tags: apache-flex

The normal structure is:

- project/

  - bin-debug
  - html-template
  - libs
  - src

I want to change it to:

- project/

  - bin-debug
  - flash/

    - html-template
    - libs
    - src

I know how to change the libs and src folders, but not html-template.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

html-template is not necessary in your application, i tried changing the path of my bin-debug. and still works well without the help of html-template and i check my bin-debug and the files that are in html-template are in bin-debug. so when launching your apps to the web you can remove the html-template.

Comment: The files in html-template are templates to the ones that end up bin-debug.  So in order to change the generated html that ends up in bin-debug you must modify the ones in html-template.  Therefore, it is necessary.